# Cannot bind TCP socket to local IP

Tags: c, sockets, bind, listen

I have my server program binding fine to 0.0.0.0 (INADDR_ANY) or 127.0.0.1 (INADDR_LOOPBACK), however I want the program to listen on my local network IP (192.168.1.24) and I keep getting this error:

Error opening the listening port 8888 (Raw TCP output): Cannot assign requested address

Here is the relevant code:

```
#define LOCAL_IP ((unsigned long int) 0x1801A8C8) //192.168.1.24
#define PORT 8888

struct sockaddr_in sa;

sa.sin_family = AF_INET;
sa.sin_port = htons(PORT);
sa.sin_addr.s_addr = LOCAL_IP; /* Bind servers to local net*/
//sa.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
```

I've also tried htonl(LOCAL_IP) and inet_addr("192.168.1.24") with no luck.

Comment: what OS? do you have a firewall, or similar security running?

Comment: What's wrong with INADDR_ANY?

Comment: Agh it is C0 and not C8!! Thank you, I really should have noticed that mistake. Fixed now! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IP you use is: 200.168.1.24

Use:

```
sa.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.1.24");
```

instead. 
Make sure the port isn't already in use. (use the program netstat) Have you closed the socket correctly, at tests before?

Comment: s_addr accepts a network long. so the backwards hex address is fine, the mistake was C8 = 200 when I should have had C0 = 192. Thanks for pointed that out!

Answer (score 1):

you can not assign any string or integer to the `sa.sin_addr.s_addr`.

So you need to cast it into suitable format.
The statement you have written `sa.sin_addr.s_addr = LOCAL_IP` will be replaced as

```
sa.sin_addr.s_addr =192.168.1.24
```

Which is causing the problem.

Use `inet_addr(LOCAL_IP)` instead, it should work.